# AngularJs form types and browser compatibility

Tags: html, forms, angularjs

My question about AngularJs that I can't seem to google my way out of just yet has to do with the way Angular handles forms and form validation.

Ideally I want to make my form cross-browser compatible and use the 'Angular-way' of handling forms. Commonly one would set the novalidate attribute on the form tag because that disables any html5 related form validation the browser wants to do.

But, and this is the thing: does that also mean that Angular handles the way inputs of, say, type="email" and does the browser ignore them? Does Angular guard the fact that the user enters a properly formatted email instead of the browser's implementation of the input type="email" field? And thus does Angular mask the input as well?

I ask because there are several useful types (like email and url) that aren't strictly cross-browser, but I'd really like to make a universal form with Angular's goodies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends a bit on what you expect your validation to do. Take the `email` field as an example. If you look at [the quirks documentation](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs.html) you will see the automatic validation for the field type works in most browsers except for IE9 and Sarafi. Bringing angular into the mix doesn't change this at all so your standard validation isn't going to work in all browsers.

That said, Angular actually is binding the value of the field to a variable via model binding. So it doesn't rely on the browser validation entirely but actually provides its own validation. I checked [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D), and even on Safari for Mac, the validation works excellently. Even with this in mind, I would still recommend opening [the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KFs4m0sgkj1xJOvzeIcv?p=preview) and trying out what fields you need to validate on all browsers you really need to support.

One final thought is that Angular itself is no longer IE8 compatible. Although the team doesn't intend to break IE8, they aren't testing in it any more ([See here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) for details). In other words - if you need really old browser support you are going to have to test that yourself!